# Prove $a_n = \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is monotone $n \ge 0$.

Tags: analysis, monotone-functions

> Prove $a_n = \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is monotone $n \ge 0$.

To be monotone it must be either increasing or decreasing, so:

$a_n \ge a_{n-1}$ or $a_n \le a_{n-1}$

$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \ge? \sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1} $

$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1} \ge? \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n}$

I know that $\sqrt{n+1} \ge \sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n} \ge \sqrt{n-1}$

But I can't make a statement about their sum since they have opposite signs that is one is greater or equal and the other is less or equal.

Can you help me to figure out the solution?

Comment: If you calculate $a_0$ and $a_1$ (and possibly $a_2$ for good measure), you can easily see which way the sequence is _not_ monotone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, for $n\geq 1$,
$$ (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1})^2 = n+1+2\sqrt{n^2-1}+n-1 = 2n+2\sqrt{n^2-1}\leq 2n +2n=4n,  $$
so that
$$ \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1} \leq  2\sqrt{n} \quad \iff\quad  \sqrt{n+1}- \sqrt n \leq  \sqrt n - \sqrt{n-1}. $$

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

use the conjugate

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{b_n}$$

now prove tha $(b_n)$  is increasing and conclude that $(a_n)$ is decreasing.

Comment: $\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n+1} \ge? \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}$ => $\sqrt{n+2} \ge? \sqrt{n}$ => increasing since $n+2 \ge n$ but can you clarify how is that helping me?

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan if the denominator increases, the fraction  decreases.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\\a_{n+1}\le a_{n}<=>
\\\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}\le2\sqrt{n}<=>
\\(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1})^2\le(2\sqrt{n})^2<=>
\\\sqrt{(n-1)(n+1)}=\sqrt{n^2-1}\le \sqrt{n^2}=n
$$